Help to load windows VST om ubuntu studio 23.10
I installed Ubuntu Studio 23.10, and after some google search, I am getting more and more confused... it seems there are a lot of ways to do it, using yabridge, with wine and pulse audio, with carla, winehq,etc. But as I read, pipewire is supposed to be better and less latency than pulse audio, in fact is the default audio engine in ubuntu studio 23.10. But I see I can change to pulseaudio in the audio control too... so, I want to try to load some windows vst on reaper with pipewire, but I am not sure what I need... it's supposed pipewire replace pulseaudio and jack, so I will not need it anymore, right?How can I do it if there is no yabrigde?  How should I do it, install the vst with winehq,  and then??
Please, point me in the right direction
Thanks

Note to close voters: remember that Ubuntu studio is supported on this site, and that 23.10 is still supported. What topics can I ask about here?
